# WebApi 2.0 Endpoint not being hit with decimal and int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TraderController : Controller
{
}
```

and the following endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IList<Trader>), 200)]
[Route("/find/{category:int}/{latitude:decimal}/{longitude:decimal}/")]
public IActionResult FindTraders(int category, decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
{ 

}
```

However when I use an `HTTP GET` I am getting a `404` error:

```
http://localhost:59405/api/trader/find/3/41.14271100000001/-8.611171499999955/
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? There are other endpoints being hitting, just not this one. Could it be to do with the decimals in the route?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use HTTP GET like

http://localhost:59405/api/trader/find?category=3&latitude=41.14271100000001&longitude=-8.611171499999955

or try changing the endpoint url to

```
[Route("/find/{category=category:int}/{latitude=latitude:decimal}/{longitude=longitude:decimal}/")]
```

Comment: I've tired both combinations you listed above and neither work? I added the trailing / to avoid IIS thinking the endpoint was a file (but I have tried with and without and it is still causing a 4040 error) Any other ideas?